# Unhandled Exception NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The Code represents the line of code that has errors according to the line pointed out by the console

Error is showing in three portion.
first one:

new FlickrPhotoList.fromJson (package:flutter_app_new_flutter/flickerPhotoList.dart:22:26)

---

```
 import 'package:flutter_app_new_flutter/model.dart';

class FlickrPhotoList {
  int page;
  int pages;
  int perpage;
  int total;
  List<FlickrPhoto> photo;

  FlickrPhotoList({
    this.page,
    this.pages,
    this.perpage,
    this.total,
    this.photo
  });

  factory FlickrPhotoList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {

    var list = parsedJson['photo'] as List;
    List<FlickrPhoto> photoList = list.map((i) => FlickrPhoto.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return FlickrPhotoList(
        page: parsedJson['page'],
        pages: parsedJson['pages'],
        perpage: parsedJson['perpage'],
        total: parsedJson['total'],
        photo: photoList);
  }
}
```

2nd error is showing in below:

new FlickrResult.fromJson (package:flutter_app_new_flutter/flickerResult.dart:15:37)

---

```
import 'package:flutter_app_new_flutter/flickerPhotoList.dart';

    class FlickrResult {
      FlickrPhotoList photos;
      String stat;
    
      FlickrResult({
        this.photos,
        this.stat
      });
    
      factory FlickrResult.fromJson(Map<dynamic, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    
        var photoList = FlickrPhotoList.fromJson(parsedJson['photos']);
    
        return FlickrResult(
            photos: photoList,
            stat: parsedJson['stat']
        );
      }
    }
```

here's the third error:

_SearchState.getSearchWallpapers. (package:flutter_app_new_flutter/search.dart:47:33)

---

```
getSearchWallpapers(String query) async{

    String requestUrl = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=b099758ce0d1e1bf8697f8491f7fb5fc&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&safe_search=1&text=$query";
    var file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(requestUrl);
    http.Response response = await http.get(requestUrl);
    String lines = await file.readAsString();


    setState(() {
      Map userMap = jsonDecode(lines);
      flickrData = FlickrResult.fromJson(userMap);
      resultsCount = flickrData.photos.photo.length;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It happen to me yesterday not some website i fix it by returning the response with title. the error for No such Method error is when your model is not matching API response from website or server is not providing your request example this is the error

```
return FlickrPhotoList(
        page: parsedJson['page'],
```

check parsedJson is providing 'page'; so first request with postman or any and read your API response.

The second one will work when we improve when
for third One please also post search.dart